# In C# how to override the Finalize() method?

Tags: c#

Following function giving compilation error "Do not override object.Finalize. Instead, provide a destructor."

```
protected override void Finalize()
{           
    this.Dispose();
    base.Finalize();
}
```

Answer (score 22):

The finalizer method is called `~name()` replacing "name" with your class name.

The C# compiler will generate the finalizer from this.

But note:

1. Only use a finaliser if you really need it: your type *directly* contains a native resource (a type composing a wrapper just uses the Dispose pattern).
2. Consider specialising `SafeHandle` rather than writing your own.
3. Implement the dispose pattern to allow callers to release the resource quickly.
4. Ensure both your Dispose and Finalizer are idempotent—they can be safely called multiple times.

e.g.

```
class MyClass : IDisposable {
  private IntPtr SomeNativeResource;

  ~MyClass() {
    Dispose(false);
  }

  public void Dispose() {
    Dispose(true);
  }

  protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
    if (disposing) {
      // Dispose any disposable fields here
      GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    ReleaseNativeResource();
  }
}
```

Subclasses can override `Dispose(bool)` to add any addition fields they add and call the base implementation.

EDITED: To add example and notes about when to finalise.

Comment: Did you miss **void**?

Comment: @LeiYang: Yes: twice. And, after almost 6 years(!), now fixed.

Answer (score 9):

You don't.

Listen to the compiler. You shouldn't override Finalize. Instead, you should implement IDisposible and override Dispose.

Unless you explicitly need to free resources held directly by the object, you should be able to do everything you need to in the Dispose method.

But if you must:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass() { ... } // Constructor
    public ~MyClass() { ... } // Destructor/Finalizer
}
```

Just be careful because Finalizers are tricky and if implemented improperly can carry some pretty hefty performance overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Listen to compiler errors, they are wise beyond their years (unless you really need to, in the rare case, actually mess with the finalizer...the naming's a bit backwards in C#).

You should instead implement `Dispose()`, making your class implement [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx?ppud=4), like this:

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
{
  public void Dispose()
  {
    //cleanup
  }
}
```

Then when using your class, wrap it in a [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx), like this:

```
using(var mc = new MyClass()) {
 //use it for things
} //it gets disposed here
```

Comment: Then when using your class, wrap it in a using, like this:

using(var mc = new MyClass()) { 
 //use it for things 
} //it gets disposed here


Please elaborate.....
as i havnt us "using"...

Comment: @Ramakant - `using()` you use when you want to dispose an object ASAP, like a file handle for example, like this: `using (var r = File.OpenText("myFile.log")) { //do stuff with the reader.. }`, at the end of that statement, the file handle is closed ASAP, freeing up locks and resources.